# How to host a windowless ActiveX control in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, activex

I'm hosting a Flash ActiveX control in my WinForms application. It works OK, however, background transparency does not work. Setting the WMode property of the control to "transperent" is supposed to make it windowless (like in browsers). I think it does just that (since it removes the background color and only the content remains) - except the AxHost control paints a fixed white background under it. What do I have to do to get rid of that white background?

Comment: .NET doesn't support windowless controls.  WMode does something entirely different, http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html#main_Using_Window_Mode__wmode__values_

Comment: [They do it somehow](http://f-in-box.com/dotnet/#feature_transparency). And if WMode=transparent doesn't make the control windowless, I don't know how else it handles transparency then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [TransparencyKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) to white on the containing form?

Comment: That would make the whole window transparent. I don't think that's the point.